# How'd I populate object key values when it comes to react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I've looked this up online but seeing a lot of conflicting answers/ways to achieve this in terms of using React hooks.
I just want want to populate the object with values that are stored in `localStorage`.

For something I'd thought would be pretty straightforward turned out to be confusing for me. With the current code below - empty strings are being returned for each key value pair except for `likes` as that's hardcoded.

What am I doing wrong and how can I rectify this?  Open to all suggestions/improvements :).

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    'email': '',
    'name': '',
    'photoUrl': '',
    'likes': 1,
    'UserID': ''
});

let email = localStorage.getItem('email');
let name = localStorage.getItem('name');
let getImg = localStorage.getItem("img");
let userId = localStorage.getItem('UserID');
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');

setUserData({
    'email': email,
    'name': name,
    'photoUrl': getImg,
    'likes': 1,
    'UserID': userId
});

console.log(userData);
```

Comment: You are setting to state. You need to set localStorage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: You might find this interesting https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/

Comment: @mkaatman wow... this truly's interesting - thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `useEffect` to load persistent state after the first render:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const persistUserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist_user'));
    if (persistUserData) {
        setUserData({
            ...persistUserData 
        });
    }
}, []);
```